# how can I use auto_ptr as member variable that handles another member variable

Tags: c++, auto-ptr

I have a class like this:

```
class A 
{

 private:

 B* ptr;

}
```

But B ptr is shared among different A objects.
How can I use auto_ptr so that when A gets destructed B stays on so that other A objects that point to the same ptr can continue without issues.
Does this look ok:

```
class A
{
public:

 auto_ptr< B > m_Ptr;

private:

 B* ptr;

}
```

what are the different ways people have implemented this and any issues/advantages they saw one to another...
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're looking for is shared_ptr.  It handles exactly this type of scenario.

- http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm

This is a part of the BOOST library though and not STL so it may not be available on your particular platform.  However if you google around a bit you can find a lot of standalone refcounted pointer implementations that will satisfy your needs here.

Answer (score 3):

If I'm understanding your question clearly, I would recommend using `::std::tr1::shared_ptr` or `::boost::shared_ptr`.

This article is [a good tutorial on shared_ptr in TR1](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_mfc/stl/article.php/c15361__1/).  The boost thing is basically the same.  I would recommend using the TR1 version if you have it because all C++ compilers are supposed to support TR1 where boost is an add-on library you might not be able to find everywhere.